How do I lose fat without losing what little muscle i have?
I'm skinny fat. (Little muscle with alot of fat). I don't wanna lose what little muscle I have but want to lose fat. What do I do?

I would suggest the following points

Use a small calorie deficit. Restricting too much can lower your basal metabolic rate and your muscles mass. You don't want that, so aim a calorie deficit between 200 and 700 per day (read more on that, there are different recommendations out there). Main point here: Don't overdo it!
Train. If you use your muscles your body will be less likely to get rid of them. I would make a fokus on muscle training but also do some cardio in order to boost the fat burning.
Consume enough proteins. You want a calorie deficit but pay attention you get enough of proteins.
Be patient. I don't know how much you weigh and how much you want to loose. But since I recommend to aim for a small calorie deficit the process will last some time. But the benefit is that you will see long term results and hopefully no yo-yo effects. Good luck!

